# Get the view name in the page.tpl.php file

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-views

#### How can I get the current view name inside the page.tpl.php file?

#### Details:

If I want to apply special code inside page.tpl.php for a certain node I can use the node number

```
if($node->nid == 35){
   //do something special for this node id
}
```

But The pages generated by the views module don't have a nid, They have a view name, How can I get this node name using php, I need to get something like this.

```
if(//node-name == "view1")
   //do something special for this page generated by views module
```

I use a work around for now, I use current_path() but I need a more reliable solution because the path may change!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question (Drupal 7)..

In order to get the current view name in the page.tpl use:

```
$page["#views_contextual_links_info"]["views_ui"]["view_name"]
```

In order to get the name of the page inside the current view use:

```
$page["#views_contextual_links_info"]["views_ui"]["view_display_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the view, there is a part called 'Theme Information', there shows a list of possible template files for theming the view or its components.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I use Theme Information for rendering the view and its fields, but I am looking for a way to do simpler things like setting a flag true or false in the page based on the view name.